# Files created in Vagrant centos/7 do not appear in Windows

Tags: vagrant, rsync, file-writing

I have primarily used Ubuntu boxes in Vagrant and in those any files created within the box have been successfully synced to Windows also. Usually things like `git pull`.

However, I now have `centos/7` and cannot get any files to sync to Windows. If you create a file in `/vagrant` it never appears anywhere in Windows - not under `C:\cygwin64\` nor `C:\vm\machine`. When I `vagrant reload` the box, all the files created inside the box are gone, except configuration files eg. `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. Any changes in them are still present upon `vagrant reload` and also `vagrant halt; vagrant up`.

[image]

Here's the Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8086, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3386, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant"
  # I have also tried the following:
  # config.vm.synced_folder "C:/vm/machine", "/vagrant"
  # config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "rsync", disabled: false
end
```

When doing `vagrant up`, both methods  for synced_folder display this:
`==> default: Rsyncing folder: /cygdrive/c/vm/machine/ => /vagrant`

I have tried doing `vagrant up` from both `cmd.exe` and also from the Cygwin64 Terminal (under `/c/vm/machine`). Neither of them create files to the Windows directory, which is in `C:\vm\machine`.

What do I need to do to make files created in the box also sync to Windows?

When I try the same in an Ubuntu box, the file appears in Windows and does not disappear:
[image]

This is the Vagrantfile of the Ubuntu box:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "v0rtex/xenial64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8083, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3303, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5000, host: 5003, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8003, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9090, host: 9093, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9091, host: 9193, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

end
```

Upon `vagrant up` for the Ubuntu box, I see this:
`==> default: Mounting shared folders...`
`default: /vagrant => C:/vm/ubu1604-64`

Comment: Wow, what are the odds that a similar question with a similar answer appeared just a few days apart :) Yes, the question added by @Frédèric Henri is the same as this, including the answer.

Comment: yep there's been a few questions recently about this box, seems there's a trend to use this box

Answer (score 3):

The solution is as follows:

1. Change the Vagrantfile synced_folder part to this:
   `config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox", disabled: false`
2. And then run this command in the directory where the Vagrantfile is:
   `vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`
3. Then do either `vagrant reload` if it was already running, or `vagrant up` otherwise.
4. It will run for quite a while - for me it took about 7 minutes altogether. However, it is a one-time install, so all future `vagrant up`'s will take a normal amount of time.

After that, the files created in the `/vagrant` directory will also appear in Windows `C:\vm\machine` (for example) and will persist between Vagrant sessions, ie. `vagrant halt` + `vagrant up`